# Typescript: Resolve Package from different location than node_modules

Tags: typescript

I am learning typescript and I would love to begin experimenting packages creation.

Here is my folder structure for the moment:

```
myProject/
├── node_modules/
├── src/
│   ├── app
│       ├── index.ts
│   ├── packages
│       ├── database
│           ├── index.ts
├── package.json
├── tsconfig.json
```

As you can see, my `src` folder is divided into `app` that will contain my application implementation and a `package` folder that is supposed to be more "abstract", in order to become one day a package eventually.

What I would like, would be to access to my packages modules writing the following in my app folder:

```
import Database from 'packages/database';
```

instead of

```
import Database from '../packages/database/index';
```

I looked around the `paths` configuration into the `tsconfig.json` file but I could not get it to work:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {

    ...

    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "packages": ["src/packages"]
    }
  }
}
```

I would also like to keep access to the `node_modules` folder of course...

**How could I achieve that?**

Thank your for your replies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the best solution for you would be to divide your work into several packages:

For example, you would have a package-database package that would make all the database related work for you.

In order to do that, you need to modify your structure a little bit:

```
myProject/
├── node_modules/
├── src/
│   ├── app
│       ├── index.ts
│   ├── packages
│       ├── database
│           ├── SomeClass.ts
│           ├── index.ts
├── package.json
├── tsconfig.json
```

Then make all the exports in your `database/index.ts` file:

```
import SomeClass from './SomeClass'
import SomeOtherClass from './SomeOtherClass'

export {SomeClass, SomeOtherClass}
```

You would the be able to access it from your app folder typing:

```
import {SomeClass} from 'package-database';
```

Of course, you also need to modify your `tsconfig.json`, you were close to it:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {

    ...

    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
        "package-database": ["src/packages/database"]
        }
    } 
}
```